# How can messages in Activemq queue/topics be persisted while using KahaDB?

Tags: activemq-classic

More specifically, right now when activemq is restarted, the enqueue/dequeue message count for queue and topic changes back to 0 but I would like activemq to persist messages using KahaDB so that even after an activemq restart the counter doesn't switch back to 0 but shows the cumulative count. Any pointers will really help.

I am using activemq version - 5.4.3 and all default settings.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have KahaDB configured and are sending Messages with the persistent property enabled (the default) then they will be stored and reloaded for all the Queues or Topics that had durable subscribers.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I have kahaDB configured like below in the activemq.xml:
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
brokerName="localhost" persistent="true"
dataDirectory="${activemq.base}/data"
destroyApplicationContextOnStop="true">
<persistenceAdapter>
 <kahaDB directory="${activemq.base}/data/kahadb"/>
 </persistenceAdapter>
</broker>
 
Msgs are now persisted after aq startup as shown by Number of Pending msgs counter however #msgs de/enqueued go back to 0. Is this right? Is it possible to see cumulative count for de/enqueued msgs even after aq startup? THanks!

Comment: Those are run time stats and such aren't persisted.  You should see the depth of your queues on restart but the stats will be reset and grow as the queues become used.